# Can't import pixi in module

Tags: module, pixi.js

This seems so simple, but I just can't get pixi to work in my module.

in the index.html

```
<script id="main" type="module" src="./src/index2.js"></script>
```

in the index2.js

```
import * as PIXI from './pixi.js';

let app = new PIXI.Application();
```

Error: Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.Application is not a constructor

I have the pixi file in the right place. Can't figure out why I can't get this thing to work. Do I need any other support files? Thanks

Comment: Cn you check console and network tab in browser devtools? Are there any errors / 404's etc? (something that indicates failed load)

Comment: Yes. Just the error mentioned above occurs. I downloaded pixi.js here: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases This is correct right?

Answer (score 2):

Oh weird. With my limited understanding of modules, I thought you could never just go like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/pixi.js"></script>
<script id="main" type="module" src="./src/index2.js"></script>
```

I thought with modules, a module could not communicate with scripts included this way. Turns out they can I guess. That was the big thing missing this whole time...I think.